# Regular expression to match pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get matches for commands like this;

```
[AUTR| <version_software> | <version_protocol> | <msg> ]
[PING]
```

What is the regular expression that find this matches for the first command?

```
AUTR
version_software
version_protocol
msg
```

this is the code that parse that:

```
String[] tokens =  msg.replace('<',' ').replace('>',' ').replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').split("\\|");
for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) tokens[i] = tokens[i].trim();
```

I'm only wondering how it can be done with a regex solution.

EDIT:

I'm trying to match groups with easier expressions, and with this code the call to m.groupCount returns one... but when I try to print it... it throws this exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found"

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w+])");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("[AUTR]");

    for (int i=0; i<m.groupCount();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
```

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Sounds like ^\[(AUTR)|\s<(version_software)>\s|\s<(version_protocol)>\s|\s<(msg)\s]$ would do the trick perfectly.

Comment: `"[AUTR| <version_software> | <version_protocol> | <msg> ]".split("[\\[\\]|\\s<>]+")` return you an array of items

Comment: I have a lot of command descriptors and I want to retrieve the parameters names, and 'yes' I can parse it easy... but I wonder how it is done with a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
http://fiddle.re/6ykc

Regular Expression:

```
\[([\w]+)(\s*\|\s*<([\w. ]+)>\s*)*\]
```

Java Regex String:

```
"\\[([\\w]+)(\\s*\\|\\s*<([\\w. ]+)>\\s*)*\\]"
```

Note that this is for variable commands now and that all extra parameters must match the following character set [a-zA-Z_0-9. ] (Includes periods and spaces).

**Issue:** There is an issue with variable length commands that you cannot capture more than one group with a variable type grouping.

> The captured input associated with a group is always the subsequence that the group most recently matched. If a group is evaluated a second time because of quantification then its previously-captured value, if any, will be retained if the second evaluation fails. Matching the string "aba" against the expression (a(b)?)+, for example, leaves group two set to "b". All captured input is discarded at the beginning of each match. 
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg

**EDIT 2:**

In order to get all of them you can do 2 regular expressions, one to grab the command:

```
String command_regex = "\\[([\\w]+)";
```

And find that and then find the parameters which you can use the <> as your key character to select:

```
String parameters = "<([\\w. ]+)>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string_to_match);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

**ORIGINAL**:

Not exactly sure on the formatting, are the "<" and ">" and "|" required? And what are the formats for the command, version_software, version_protocol and message? This is my attempt though for regular expressions (tested in Python)

```
\[(\w+)\s*\|\s*<([\w.]+)>\s*\|\s*<(\w+)>\s*\|\s*<([\w\s]+)>\s*\]
```

You need to make sure to escape the brackets and the pipe symbols (I added \s* conditions between because I don't know if there will be spaces or not. If you do:

```
>> search.re("expression above", line) 
>> search.groups()
```

It should give all tokens in python at least. I left it more hardcoded to allow room for adjustments on each token you wanted to grab, otherwise you could reduce the last 3 parts by making it a group and saying to repeat 3 times. Let me know results?

Comment: Sorry.. but it does not work... maybe the scape characters... because Java said that the regex had illegal scape chars and I have added a backslash to each one in your regex to let me compile...  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w+)\\s*\\|\\s*<([\\w.]+)>\\s*\\|\\s*<(\\w+)>\\s*\\|\\s*<([\\w\\s]+)>\\s*\\]");... but does not match anything...

Comment: Ah okay, I will look into Java then since I'm using Python.

Comment: What are you using to test these expressions?

Comment: I'm using   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([w+])");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("[AUTR]"); and I'm testing with this online tool too http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Well of course it doesn't match [AUTR], the pattern is trying to match [AUTR| <version_software> | <version_protocol> | <msg> ]. So you want it to match all types of patterns? It seemed like you wanted one for first pattern of commands. For one command it'd just be "\\[([\\w]+)\\]" (No spaces around command allowed).

Comment: I tested your expression with the right input... Now I'm trying to match the command with no params because it is suposed to be the easier... but commands can have a variable number of parameters...

Comment: See the edit I just made with the fiddle link. Thanks for the link, made testing so much faster. Darn I just realized the grouping is weird now. Moop for variable length expressions.

Comment: I have seen your second edit and it works that way... I though that it can be used and OR to match one expression for commans and another expression for parameters... a lot of thanks